# What's wrong with my website?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, internet-explorer

I've launched a website: .. But it does not work in IE 8 (the Flash movie does not load). It works fine in every other browser. I've no clue what's wrong or where to look..

Any ideas?

Comment: Flash disabled in your browser maybe? Check security settings....

Comment: No, other websites with flash load fine. Does it work on your IE8?

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nachtlenzen.nl%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: What's the code you use for it, for one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a conditional statement which prevents the object from being loaded in IE:

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="nachtlens_60sec_player_2.swf" width="498" height="320">
                <!--<![endif]-->
                <div>
                    <h1>adobe flashplayer</h1>
                    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
                </div>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
```

I would recommend you use a loader such as SWFObject for loading the flash rather than use this code anyway:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/